# why does every image have it's own URL?

Tags: image, web, post, get

Im learning web dev now and am curious about this. I know you can do GET/POST HTML files with a specific URL. But why does every image need to have it's own URL? It seems to be inefficient. Why can't we embed an image into an HTML file or be able to get multiple images from a single URL.

Comment: Every image needs a URL because every image is a unique image.  `mysite.com/img/potato.png` and `mysite.com/img/apple.png` are 2 separate images on my website for example.  Even if there was a way to embed image data in HTML, the image data would need to be there, so it makes much more sense to refer to another image file from HTML.  Think of how files are stored on your computer.  Every file is stored at `\Users\yourname\Documents\images` and the images would be `potato.png` and `apple.png`.  You cannot have the same name go to 2+ files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every single image is a separate resource, to use them in UI, you need to call them separately. But it doesn't mean we can't avoid calling multiple HTTP requests as number of images we need. There are several methods to avoid them.

> But why does every image need to have it's own URL? It seems to be
>   inefficient.

To call multiple images in a same HTTP request itself. One of the method is [CSS Sprite](https://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/).

> Why can't we embed an image into an HTML file

This is too possible with using images as encoded data saved in [Sass variables](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/variables) and retrieving them into UI via [data-uri](https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/using-data-uris-speed-website). But this method has it's own pros & cons. So choose wisely.